# How get the same model using two different adapters in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, ember-data, adapter

I have `post` model, and in posts route I get data using:

`this.store.filter('post', this.params(), function(post) { /* some code */ });`

Now I have second route, for search engine, and I can connect with this like that:

```
var uri = 'api/v1/search/';
vat that = this;
return Ember.$.getJSON(uri).then(function(response) {
    store.pushPayload('post', response);
    return that.store.filter('post', that.params(), function(post) {
       // some code
    });
}
```

But because I have pagination and my model is updated dynamically, I would like to avoid using `Ember.$.getJSON` and specify different url (`'api/v1/search/'`) for a store. Is it possible? How can I do this?